# Meaning of そのくらいにして

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning behind そのくらいにして? Currently reading and this sentenced popped up.

> まあ、まあ。
> 堅苦しい挨拶はそのくらいにして、お茶でも飲んで

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is literally "leaving them (the formalities) at that extent", so you might understand the phrase as "leaving formalities aside".

(By the way, welcome! In future it would help us with your learning if you were to give us your best guess or an indication of what you think it should mean.)

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to do that next time.